# Adafruit BLE Feather doesn't show up in the iPhone Bluetooth devices list

Tags: ios, arduino, bluetooth, adafruit

I may be missing something simple or straightforward here, but if the Adafruit BLE feather has a bluetooth chip why isn't the iPhone not seeing it (in Settings->Bluetooth->Devices) but when I install the Bluefruit Connect app, its able to see it.

Unless the system (BT HW on the phone) sees it the app cannot see it. So what is preventing the settings from showing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device settings in iOS shows legacy bluetooth devices, such as handsfree audio devices, keyboards and mice.  It doesn't show BLE devices unless there is an active connection to the device (or the device has been bonded, which isn't common with Bluetooth Low Energy devices).

The Bluefruit app will search for devices that are advertising the GATT service in which it is interested.   Bluetooth settings does not do this.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. Isn't showing up in settings a prerequisite to pairing? How can I pair with it if its not shown? Also what is bonding? I am hearing it for the first time. Thanks for the response.

Comment: The typical flow you use for "pairing" is to use the settings app, but only for legacy bluetooth devices, not BLE devices.  BLE devices typically use GATT and advertise services.  Apps can scan for all BLE devices or devices advertising a particular service (e.g. Heart Rate Monitor).  Paring is the exchange of keys to allow secure communication and this happens when an app connects to a BLE peripheral it has discovered. Paring can optionally use verification (e.g PIN codes)  Bonding is the storing of keys so that secure communication can occur without the need to manually pair each time.

Comment: What is typically referred to as "pairing" is actually bonding.  See https://www.kynetics.com/docs/2018/BLE_Pairing_and_bonding/

Comment: Thanks! It's news to me that BLE devices do not show up in settings. I am still confused though. So if I create a new device that using BLE it cannot be used without the user installing the associated app? Are there any commercially available BLE devices I can buy and check on Amazon? Sorry but its my first time dealing with BLE.

Comment: You can use the app LightBlue to discover and connect to BLE devices; It is a very useful developer tool.  As I mentioned before there are many "well known" BLE services defined; Heart Rate Monitors, scales, blood glucose, Bicycle speed and cadence and so on.  If you have a device that uses these well known services then any app that supports that service will work with it (e.g. any "heart rate" app can use any BLE device that provides the standard "heart rate service").  Devices that use their own service may need a specific app, but other apps can be written if there is documentation

Comment: Another example of a useful generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool is the one from Nordic Semi, called [nRF Connect for Mobile](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile). If you are on a desktop machine with a recent version of the Chrome browser, you can use the URL `chrome://bluetooth-internals/` to do something similar.

Comment: Thanks guys. Really helpful.